# How to compile with libelf.h on Mac OS?

Tags: c, macos, compiler-errors, header-files

I am trying to compile a C program on Mac OS Catalina that uses the `libelf.h` header. I get the following error message:

```
fatal error: 'libelf.h' file not found
#include <libelf.h> 
     ^~~~~~~~~~
```

I followed [these directions](http://macappstore.org/libelf/) and installed libelf and use the `-lelf` flag with both gcc and clang. Still can't compile on Mac OS (it compiles on Ubuntu). I'm not sure where to go from here...

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/276307/installing-elf-on-mac-through-homebrew

Comment: Since macOS doesn't use ELF for its object files, code written to use ELF won't work on macOS — at least, not without a lot of hard work.

Comment: @Arnie97 Thank you, I got it to compile by doing a variation of that solution. I still couldn't include that exact elf.h file but I just had to add 'libelf/' to all the ELF-related headers, and use libelf/elf_repl.h instead of elf.h. There were missing symbols in libelf/elf_repl.h so I got the missing definitions from the elf.h that you pointed me to. Thanks!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oops, that's something I overlooked... Thanks for informing me about that.

Answer (score 0):

First: 'brew install libelf'

Then, I find the following relevant files:

```
/opt/homebrew/include/libelf/gelf.h
/opt/homebrew/include/libelf/libelf.h
/opt/homebrew/lib/libelf.a
```

which are actally symlinked to:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libelf/0.8.13_1/include/libelf/gelf.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libelf/0.8.13_1/lib/libelf.a
```

To resolve compile-time errors saying 'gelf.h' not found and 'libelf.h' not found (from #include statements), add the following to your compiler invocation:

```
-I /opt/homebrew/include
-I /opt/homebrew/include/libelf
```

To resolve link-time errors saying "library not found for -lelf", add the following to your compiler (actually linker) invocation:

```
-L /opt/homebrew/lib
```